# Find next div tag in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Question on beautiful soup in python

I have a HTML like

```
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Qualification</div>
<div class="content">THE DATA I WANT</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
```

same div tags repeats again

In this scenario:
No I'd or any unique tag's , all containing ---only div tags---

how do I get "THE DATA I WANT" text which is after Qualification
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt = '''
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Qualification</div>
<div class="content">THE DATA I WANT</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('div:contains("Qualification") ~ div').text)
```

Prints:

```
THE DATA I WANT
```

---

Or:

```
print(soup.find(text="Qualification").find_next().text)
```

---

Or:

```
print(soup.find(lambda t: t.find_previous() and t.find_previous().text == 'Qualification').text)
```

---

EDIT: To iterate over `<div>`s you can use simple for-loop:

```
for item in souped.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'div' and t.text == 'Qualification'):
    print(item.find_next().text)
```

Comment: how can get exact word "QUALIIFACTION" ,
e.g div contains only letter qualification

Comment: @O.T.BHarmonyLimited You can use `print(soup.find(lambda t: t.name=='div' and t.text=='Qualification').find_next().text)`. This will find `<div>` with text `Qualification` and then gets next element's text.

Comment: thankyou it worked :), find all is not working, Is their any way I can get all like find all does,help much appreciated . once again thanks so much 
e.g 
souped.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'div' and t.text == 'Qualification').find_next()
when I try above it shows
```
ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_next'.
```

Comment: @O.T.BHarmonyLimited you need to iterate elements found in `.find_all()`. For example `for item in soup.find_all(...):`

Comment: hi, I havetried like this     `for item in souped.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'div' and t.text == 'Qualification').find_next():
                realqualification= [item]` , but its show error attribute find_next() not found , can I get help please

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc ='''<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Qualification</div>
<div class="content">THE DATA I WANT</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>
<div class="content">Somedata</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

result = soup.find_all("div", class_="content")[3].text

print(result)
```

Output will be:

```
THE DATA I WANT
```

OR

```
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
print(soup.find(text=re.compile('^THE DATA I WANT$')))
```

OR

```
print(soup.find(string="Qualification").find_next().text)
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer :) ,  how can I get THE DATA I WANT if it's position is not fixed ,but it was always under qualification div? thanks in advance